# What's a good opposite of 'razor-thin'?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a good opposite of 'razor-thin'. It's got to have an analogy to something that's inherently a thick object. A generic adjective that fits into the template "xxx-thick" would be exactly what I'm looking for, others are okay too.

Example sentences for 'razor-thin':

- *"razor-thin slices of salmon"*
- *"the new MacBook is razor-thin"*

Comment: *big chunks of*...

Comment: It would be easier if we knew what object you have in mind, salmon or something else entirely. For if you are looking for an opposite descriptor, as in "a xxxx-thick slice", I fear you are barking up the wrong tree, the language is under no obligation to provide one.

Comment: ..."slabs of salmon, thick as a brick."

Comment: Sadly, not 'broad-brush'. Hyperbolically, 'mile-wide'.

Comment: You can't really have razor-thin slices of salmon without the fish breaking into pieces, I would have said "Parma ham". *That* you can cut thinly. Cubes. You can have cubes of cheese.... Adj. *chunky* inspired by @ermanen's suggestion.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A, Oh really? I wouldn't know, I've been vegetarian all my life. I just took the sentence from the Cambridge dictionary ;-) 
Someone actually used 'razor-thin' to talk about the new MacBook and that's when I got this question.

Comment: I think the opposite of a razor-thin computer or smartphone would be "bulky" or "clunky". @Sven: are salmon thick as bricks? I thought they were more intelligent than that. Relevant to the foodie angles, in the UK a stupid person used to be "thick as a docker's sandwich".

Comment: @DavidPugh: Any fish that ascends a 40-foot series of cascading waterfalls by main strength only to be snapped up in mid-air by a grizzly bear waiting at the top for an easy lunch is NOT going to one of the better universities. Nor is it going to spend hours working out the deeper meanings of old Jethro Tull albums.

Comment: @Sven: Yeah, they're dim as a Toc H lamp, to use another Britishism that probably died out before you were born. I was just goofing around with your "thick as bricks", which signifieth stupid. OTOH, couldn't they get a sports scholarship?

Comment: I still like [**chunky**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/chunky) it's as good as any, I cannot think of any adjective that fits with *thick*. Bulky is also good...

Comment: Could you give examples of the things that you want to describe with this term?

Comment: @Mari-LouA _razor-thin_ is rarely meant literally -- it typically means as thin as possible for the type of object in question. A thick slice of lox is still thinner than a razor-thin computer.

Answer (score 1):

- a **slab** is a very thick slice. 
  (I know, that's not an adjective.)

Other possibilities might be a

- {**hearty/ substantial/ generous**} slice.

...but if you really want the opposite of the thinnest-possible slice, you want the largest-possible slice, which is *not sliced at all*, namely, *the whole piece*!